# How NOT to trigger comboBox.SelectedIndexChange AND update it?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, combobox

I wrote a code that whenever the user picks a value from the drop-down comboBox, their choice becomes the first item (index 0) of the collection.

Example

BEFORE

> [_ MyComboBox _][v]
>
> > ```
> >      |Dog
> >      |Tree
> >      |House
> > ```

*USER CLICKS "Tree"*

AFTER

> [_ MyComboBox _][v]
>
> ```
>      |Tree
>      |Dog
>      |House
> ```

The problem is that after this operation, even though everything works fine, the comboBox remains blank and the user has no clue about what they've done.

But if I do as everyone suggests, that is `MyComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;` it triggers an inifinite loop since I'd be calling it from inside the event handler MyComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(...)

I also tried `MyComboBox.Text = string_that_contains_what_I_want_to_display;` but it triggers BOTH SelectedIndexChanged AND SelectedValueChanged.

Frankly I cannot understand why even switching from items with the same value, BOTH index and value are triggered. As far as I understand, SelectedValueChanged should only be triggered when the two items have different content.

I'd be thankful to anyone that will help me get out of this puzzle.

I just need to show the result of the sort operation in the program interface, after it's done. I could reload the whole page containing my control: it would work, but that wouldn't be very efficient.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `SelectionChangeCommitted` event instead of `SelectionChange`. The `SelectionChangeCommitted` event is only fired when the user makes a change rather than when your program makes the change for it.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and mark this as an Accepted answer (the check-mark to the left).

Comment: I marked the answer as Accepted but I can't upvote yet, I'm a new user ;)